# How to sort bill me later under the Paypal

Tags: magento-1.9

is there any way to sort PayPal and Bill me later methods in Magento, all i want is to have this order in the checkout page 1 .Paypal and 2. Bill me later. Now i have first Bill me later.

[image]

[image]

Comment: any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In magento admin panel you can set the assign a **sort order** number to each payment method, this will determine in which order they are displayed in the frontend. You can do this in:

> System -> Config -> Sales -> Payment Methods

If your payment method doesn't have this setting here, you can check in the DB and change it there. All this settings are stored in **core_config_data** table:

```
select * from core_config_data where path like '%payment%sort_order%';
```

This query will return all payment methods and they sort order, you can also change it from here.

Comment: perfect but where is for the Bill me later? I don't find the sort order for Bill me later, i want to be second after the paypal, i find the sort order for paypal, but for Bill me later i can;t find it? you find it?

Comment: take a look i edit my post here I add admin for the paypal, my sort order is ok i think, then why I still have Bill me later first?

Comment: change the sort order of paypal from 2 to 0 and check. I cant see in your screen shoot the settings for bill me later.

Comment: @RobertD I updated my answer try this. If this help you please accept my solution.

Comment: Have you find any solution of this?