# How to set Sort Order for PayPal Credit?

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, payment-methods, paypal, sort

I've been trying to set the sort order for PayPals pay with credit option. In the admin you have the option to **Enable Paypal Credit** but no sort order setting. Also in the database there's no sort order for paypal credit either that I can locate in `core_config_data` table.

PayPal Credit is always listed in the top position in the checkout payments.

I can't find anything about this except  [How to sort bill me later under the Paypal](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101601/how-to-sort-bill-me-later-under-the-paypal)

Anyone know how to set the sort order for PayPal Credit?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I solved this recently.

1) Need to access DB via PHPMyadmin, click the SQL tab, and enter this command:

`select * from core_config_data where path like '%payment%sort_order%';`

The query will display the sort order for all checkout payment method options.

2) Update the paypal_express options to a higher number in the 'value' column.

The update will move the PayPal Express and PayPal Credit options to a lower position on the checkout page. If it is not working then you need to set the option you want on the top of the list to a lower number like '0' in the value field. If you don't know which one it is then you can view the source on your checkout page. The label on the radio button will tell you which DB row to update. For example `<label for="p_method_verisign">`

Comment: It doesn't work for me. The source says it's dt_method_paypal_express_bml, then dt_method_paypal_direct, then next is dt_method_paypal_express. paypal_express_bml is Paypal Credit, paypal_direct is PayPal Credit Card Processor.

Comment: @Freejoy can you send me a link to your checkout page, the order that you want the options in, and a screenshot of the query results of [select * from core_config_data where path like '%payment%sort_order%]?